# How to wrap text in div after certain element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to be able to wrap a div around some text after the first BR in the text.

So this is how it would look in the CMS for example:

```
<div class="quote">
<p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eget ligula scelerisque, tempor justo non, pretium eros. Duis luctus pulvinar posuere. Nunc quam dui, tempor eu tincidunt et, pulvinar at quam.<br /><br />

        Sed congue nisl eget libero mollis, a rhoncus odio sollicitudin. Cras aliquet mi vel diam elementum, ac vestibulum ligula imperdiet. Nulla facilisi. Praesent vestibulum nisi odio, sed scelerisque diam molestie vitae..<br /><br />

    Sed rhoncus purus eu metus elementum hendrerit. Sed scelerisque sodales eros vel tempus. Morbi tempor risus condimentum, sagittis turpis vel, auctor odio. Fusce sed lorem non dolor fringilla accumsan. Proin metus lectus.<br /><br />

    Donec malesuada elit quis nunc ultrices dictum. Nulla quis tortor sed quam aliquet tempor. Duis porta nunc non augue fermentum rutrum. Morbi imperdiet justo et est pellentesque, sed consequat neque ultricies..<br />
    </p>
</div>
```

and I'd like the jQuery to add a div after the first BR - so it looks like:

```
<div class="quote">
    <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eget ligula scelerisque, tempor justo non, pretium eros. Duis luctus pulvinar posuere. Nunc quam dui, tempor eu tincidunt et, pulvinar at quam.<br />
<div id="space">
<br />

            Sed congue nisl eget libero mollis, a rhoncus odio sollicitudin. Cras aliquet mi vel diam elementum, ac vestibulum ligula imperdiet. Nulla facilisi. Praesent vestibulum nisi odio, sed scelerisque diam molestie vitae..<br /><br />

        Sed rhoncus purus eu metus elementum hendrerit. Sed scelerisque sodales eros vel tempus. Morbi tempor risus condimentum, sagittis turpis vel, auctor odio. Fusce sed lorem non dolor fringilla accumsan. Proin metus lectus.<br /><br />

        Donec malesuada elit quis nunc ultrices dictum. Nulla quis tortor sed quam aliquet tempor. Duis porta nunc non augue fermentum rutrum. Morbi imperdiet justo et est pellentesque, sed consequat neque ultricies..<br />
</div>
        </p>
    </div>
```

I've currently got this far with my jQuery:

```
$('.quote p br').wrapAll('<div id="space"></div>');
```

but this just grabs all the br's and adds them together in the div not the rest of the text.

JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/2pQ4r/

Comment: Let me get this straight. You want to grab a _certain amount_ of **childNodes** (either text or element), **remove** them from the parent and **append** them into a **new** div element that is then **appended** to the parent. Is this correct?

Comment: Does this work for you `$('<div id="space"/>').insertAfter('br:even');`

Comment: `<div>` is not a valid child of `<p>`. `<p>` does not allow block level descendants

Comment: Hi Hanzo,

I want to grab all the content inside those child nodes (anything after the first BR and before the close p tag).

Comment: This looks very similar to an example: http://api.jquery.com/contents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are dealing with text nodes also, the element selectors will not work, you need to deal with .contents(). So one way is to find the index of first `br` element in the contents of `quote` then find all elements after that and wrap them within a `div` like

```
$('.quote').each(function () {
    var $contents = $(this).find('p').contents(),
        $br = $(this).find('p br:first'),
        index = $contents.index($br);

    $contents.slice(index + 1).wrapAll('<div id="space"></div>');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L4qe4/)

Comment: Thank that should have been `$contents.slice(0,index).wrapAll('<div id="space"></div>');` to get (close) to what the OP asked - albeit without the first `<br/>` included

Comment: @Jamiec that will wrap the first text node from the OP's output what I can see is OP wants to wrap everything after the first `br`

Comment: Yup, just noticed my mistake.

Comment: How would you make this so it works on multiple '.quote p'? At the moment if I have two or three on the same page it takes all the content from the other two and puts them in the first.

Answer (score 1):

I know you found an answer. I'm gonna leave mine below, just in case someone doesn't want to use all that fancy good-looking jQuery. It assumes your browser has `Element.querySelector` and `Array.forEach`

```
(function () {
  function unconventionalMigrator(p) {
    var child, next, div;
    // get first br Element
    child = p.querySelector('br');
    // get nextSibling
    next = child = child.nextSibling;
    // make new div element to migrate children
    div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = 'space';// IMPLEMENTATION SPECIFIC
    // migrate children
    while (child) {
      next = child.nextSibling;// save next
      div.appendChild(child);  // move current
      child = next;            // set next
    }
    // append new div Element
    p.appendChild(div);
  }
  // get p Element
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.quote p'),unconventionalMigrator);
}())
```

Answer (score 0):

This wrapps only the first text node before `<br />`, like you wanted (using jQuery's `map` function):

```
var brs = $('.quote p br');
var nodes = brs.map(function(){
    return this.previousSibling;
});

if ( nodes.length ) {
    var firstNode = nodes[0];
    var oldText = firstNode.nodeValue;
    firstNode.nodeValue = "";
    $(firstNode).parent().prepend("<div style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">" + oldText + "</div>");
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LsSPM/2/)

If you **really** want the element **after** first node (as you stated), then just use this instead of last line (but I think that you meant 1st paragraph):

```
brs[0].remove();
$(firstNode).parent().prepend(
    "<div style=\"border: 1px solid black;\">"
    + oldText
    + "</div><br />"
);
```

Answer (score -1):

This should help you:

Use this code: http://jsfiddle.net/2pQ4r/

Just wrap your text first in some container like span. And then use:
`$('.quote p br').next().wrapAll('<div id="space"></div>');`